# How to get focused or selected value in DevExpress WPF TreeListControl?

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress, treelist

I am using DevExpress TreeListControl:

```
void TreeListView_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e) {
    string val;
    PropertyInfo[] properties =  e.NewRow.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo item in properties) {
        string x =  item.Name;
        if (x == "Id") {
            var barProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
            if (barProperty != null) {
                object[] obj = new Object[0];
                val = item.GetValue(sender, obj) as string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to get selected row value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not needed to use reflection at all. You can use the [TreeListView.FocusedNode](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTreeListView_FocusedNodetopic) property and the [TreeListView.GetNodeValue](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTreeListView_GetNodeValuetopic) method:

```
object id = treeListView.GetNodeValue(treeListView.FocusedNode,"Id");
```